# Confused about notations used in a Computer Vision paper

Tags: notation, computer-vision

I was reading a  computer vision paper for 3D reconstruction and was a bit confused by two notations: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/327805907_3D_Image_Reconstruction_from_Multi-Focus_Microscope_Axial_Super-Resolution_and_Multiple-Frame_Processing

1. $f \in R^{{N_x}\times{N_y}\times{N_z}}$, which denotes a 3D object
2. $ h(x,y;z) $

What is meant by the $N_x \times N_y \times N_z$ term and the ; symbol in h?

Sorry if this seems ignorant, I am not a math major :')

Answer (score 0):

This is a notation peculiar to ML papers;  what they mean by $\mathbb{R}^{N_x \times N_y \times N_z}$ is actually $\mathbb{R}^{N_x} \times \mathbb{R}^{N_y} \times \mathbb{R}^{N_z}$, or in simpler terms, $f$ is a three dimensional array with each dimension of length $N_x, N_y$ and $N_z$.

The semicolon is sometimes used to emphasize a semantic difference between the function arguments, but in this case, after a quick look through the paper, it seems unnecessary.

Comment: What do you mean by notation ML ?

Comment: @JeanMarie Machine Learning I assume